# App Engine Standard, Serverless VPCs, Cloud Memorystore giving significant amount of timeouts

Tags: google-app-engine, redis, google-cloud-memorystore, google-vpc

We configured our App Engine Standard python 3 service to connect to Cloud Memorystore via the Serverless VPC service (per the documentation, and other stack overflow threads).  (I've included the app.yaml config below).  This all worked well, unless an instance went idle for a little while.  Over time we saw a high volume of:

- Long unexplained hangs when making calls to Memorystore, even though they eventually worked
- `redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 110 connecting to 10.0.0.12:6379. Connection timed out.`
- `redis.exceptions.TimeoutError: Timeout reading from socket`

These happened to the point where I had to move back to App Engine Flexible, where the service runs great without any of the above problems.

My conclusion is that Serverless VPC does not handle the fact that the redis client tries hard to leave the connection to redis open all the time.  I tried a few variations of timeout settings, but nothing that helped.  Has anyone successfully deployed App Engine Standard, Memorystore, and Serverless VPC?

```
env_variables:
  REDISHOST: <IP>
  REDISPORT: 6379

network:
  name: "projects/<PROJECT-ID>/global/networks/default"

vpc_access_connector:
  name: "projects/<PROJECT-ID>/locations/us-central1/connectors/<VPC-NAME>
```

Code used to connect to Memorystore (using [redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py)):

```
REDIS_CLIENT = redis.StrictRedis(
    host=REDIS_HOST, 
    port=REDIS_PORT, 
    retry_on_timeout=True, 
    health_check_interval=30
)
```

(I tried various timeout settings but couldn't find anything that helped)

Comment: Could you please share the code that you are using to connect to Memorystore? Which Client Library are you using?

Comment: @NahuelVarela added the code that instantiates the client, thx

Comment: Have you tried to play with [warm up requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/configuring-warmup-requests)?

Answer (score 1):

I created a Memorystore instance and a Serverless VPC Access connector as stated in the docs (https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access), then deployed this sample (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard_python37/redis) from Google Cloud Platform Python doc samples repo to App Engine Standard after making some modifications:

This is my app.yaml:

```
runtime: python37

# Update with Redis instance details
env_variables:
  REDIS_HOST: <memorystore-ip-here>
  REDIS_PORT: 6379

# Update with Serverless VPC Access connector details
vpc_access_connector:
  name: 'projects/<project-id>/locations/<region>/connectors/<connector-name>'
# [END memorystore_app_yaml_standard]
```

I edited the code on main.py and used the snippet that you use to connect to the memorystore instance. It ended up like this:

```
redis_client = redis.StrictRedis(
    host=redis_host, port=redis_port,
    password=redis_password,
    retry_on_timeout=True, 
    health_check_interval=30
)
```

I edited the requirements.txt. I changed “`redis==3.3.8`” for “`redis>=3.3.0`”

Things to note:

- Make sure to use “gcloud beta app deploy” instead of “gcloud app deploy” since it is needed in order for the Serverless VPC Access connector to work.
- Make sure that the authorized network you set to the memorystore instance is the same that you select for the Serverless VPC Access connector

This works as expected for me, could you please check if this works for you?

Comment: Hi Joey, this is basically the steps we followed as well.  It does work initially and connects to Redis just fine.  However once the instances have gone idle for a while (but not killed off) then they struggle to connect to Redis.  If you have min idle set to 0 you might not see this as much with a test app.  Basically if you hit the app, wait 5 minutes or so, make sure the app is still running, and then hit it again you'll start to see timeouts.  We saw this to the tune of thousands of these exceptions over a few days.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use [min idle instance](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#min_idle_instances) option, so you will have at least one idle instance to wait to serve your traffic. Bear in mind that this may change your [billing cost](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing). Also here you can find a [billing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/).
If the min idle instances are set to 0 there are no available instances to serve your traffic when the requests are starting and may this be the reason of having exceptions.

Comment: Hi @chainicko, I don't think cold starts are my issue, the issue is with instances that are around for a while, but idle